# Move files from multiple folders to a corresponding destination folder

Tags: powershell

I am trying to figure out how to do a ForEach on moving files from a source to destination location.

I have tired the below code, but cant get it to work :(

```
$SrcLocations = @('Src1','Src2','Src3')
$DestLocations = @('dest1','dest2','dest3')


function Move-Files {
  Write-Output "$(Get-TimeStamp): $SrcLocations file move to Remote Storage started" | Out-file $OutputLogFile -append
  $FileMoves = get-childitem $SrcLocations
  Foreach ($file in $FileMoves) {
  Move-Item -Path $SrcLocations -Destination $DestLocations -force
  if (!$?) {
  "File $($file.name) failed moving to Remote Storage" | out-file $OutputLogFile -append
           }
  }
 Time-Delay-Move-Files
 Write-Output "$(Get-TimeStamp): File moved to $DestLocations" | Out-file $OutputLogFile -append
}
```

Comment: You are trying to move each source to its respective destination yes? Not any other combinations. What is `Time-Delay-Move-Files`? Have you considered robocopy for operations like this? It would have better logging capabilites

Comment: Explain what is not working.

Comment: Hi Matt, The Time-Delay-Move-Files had been a 10 second delay function before moving to the next from old code I had tried.

Yes just need to move from each source to its respective destination folder.

Had considered robocopy, but thought this should be doable as well :(

Comment: Hi Jereon, Files fail to move using this code, but if I create three functions for each and split out the source and destination to each one it works a treat, but would like it to complete as a single function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For-Each isnt ideal in your case because you need a value out of both the source and destination arrays. Assuming both arrays are the same length, you can use a For loop such as:

```
$SrcLocations = @('Src1','Src2','Src3')
$DestLocations = @('dest1','dest2','dest3')


For($i = 0; $i -lt $SrcLocations.Count; $i++){
    Write-Host "Moving $($SrcLocations[$i]) to $($DestLocations[$i])"
}
```

Outputs

```
Moving Src1 to dest1
Moving Src2 to dest2
Moving Src3 to dest3
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank You :)

Added **Move-Item** and working perfectly.

```
$SrcLocations = @('Src1','Src2','Src3')
$DestLocations = @('dest1','dest2','dest3')


For($i = 0; $i -lt $SrcLocations.Count; $i++){
    Move-Item -Path $($SrcLocations[$i]) -Destination $($DestLocations[$i]) -force
    Write-Host "Moving $($SrcLocations[$i]) to $($DestLocations[$i])"
}
```